# Google app script to update Form from Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to fill a Google Form multiple choice with a row of data from a Google Sheet.
I can get the row text into an Array, but somehow when I use the method .setChoiceValues(), I get a:

```
Exception: Invalid conversion for item type: TEXT. (line 36, file "PopulateBudgetCategories")
```

According to Google documentation, such method receives a String[], but fails, throwing the same expection, even with the following code:

```
studentNames = ['⛽ Car', ' Healthcare', ' Mobile phones'];
formExpenseTypes.asListItem().setChoiceValues(studentNames);
```

Has anyone got an idea of how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### Your error implies that `formExpenseTypes` is an item of type `TEXT`

- `asListItem()` means that you are retrieving an item as a dropdown question, however if your question was not a dropdown question when you created it
- As of now, it is not possible to convert item types with Apps Script
- There is a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/65557735) for it on Google's Public Issue Tracker that you can "star" if you are interested
- In the mean time - you need to create an item as the type of item you want it to be
- If you desire to change the item type programmatically - you need to delete the existing item and create a new one
- If you want to create choices for a multiple choice item (opposed to a dropdown item!), you need to retrieve it as `asMultipleChoiceItem()`, not as `asListItem()`

Sample:

```
function myFunction() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
  var items = form.getItems();
  var formExpenseTypes = items[items.length-1];
  studentNames = ['⛽ Car', ' Healthcare', ' Mobile phones'];
  formExpenseTypes.asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoiceValues(studentNames);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry it was all a mistake by me. In one of hte edits I think the form control's ID's changed order and I was actually trying to add Choices to a Text question.